# Migration from SQL Server to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to convert the SQL Server stored procedure to snowflake - can you please help us?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.analyticsGetFilterNames 
    @product NVARCHAR(20) = '',
    @franchise NVARCHAR(20) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @product = 'Menus' AND @franchise = 'Nissan'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM table1
    END
    ELSE -- Triage & other brands
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM table2
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a `Tabular SQL UDF(TSUDF)` in snowflake :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION analyticsGetFilterNames ( 
  product NVARCHAR(20)
, franchise NVARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE (<output_col_names>) AS 
$$
  IF product = 'Menus' and franchise = 'Nissan'
  BEGIN
     SELECT * from table1
  END
  ELSE -- Triage & other brands
  BEGIN
     SELECT * from table2
  END
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only write JS in Snowflake's Stored Procedure, the SQL scripting feature is not yet publicly available.

Please refer to the documentation on how to write JS SP in Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html